# FastAPI server becoming unresponsive when sending Twilio message

Tags: python, twilio, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI app (obvs) that has an endpoint which uses Twilio's Client to send a message sync. This has not worked. I made a bare bones python file that just constructs the client and creates the message and it works fine so I do not suspect it is twilio itself. When making a call using the twilio client the server hangs/freezes. It never times out. If I make a file change during this period the reloader freezes as well (I'm assuming since the server has become non-responsive). This happens regardless if I am using a sync or async path def for this route. Other async and sync routes seem to work fine (I haven't gotten around to testing them all yet).

```
fastapi==0.104.1
twilio==8.2.0
uvicorn==0.23.2
starlette==0.27.0
```

I am running the app locally like so (I've also called uvicorn directly from the command line):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('app:app', reload=True, port=5002)
```

I have a router in a separate file and call app.include_router(<the_router>) in a builder function for the app. Here's the twilio client (we have our own lil wrapper):

```
from twilio.rest import Client
...get env variables

class TwilioAPI
    def __init__(self, phone_number: str):
        self.client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
        self.phone_number = phone_number

    def send_sms(self, body: str):
        # we enter the function, but this never returns/resolves
        message = self.client.messages.create(
            messaging_service_sid=messaging_service_sid,
            body=body,
            to=self.phone_number,
        )
        return message.sid
```

The route in question looks like this:

```
@router.post("/endpoint")
def send_message_or_whatever(input: Input):
    ...get data from input, construct message
    ...we hit our database here and this works
    twilio_api_client = CreateAnInstanceOfOurTwilioClient()
    twilio_api_client.send_sms(message) <--- this is where it goes sideways
    return stuff
```

All the examples I have found on twilio's own blog do something like

```
@router.post('/endpoint')
async def do_something():
    client = twilio.rest.Client() # synchronous client
    client.messages.create(...create message params)
```

Stuff I have tried:

using async and sync path definitions. Even though we are "waiting" on twilio in a sync function it shouldn't really matter? We wait for the db at other points which is a network call with no issue. Right now I don't even care if its not the most optimal thing for performance.  The client doesn't return a future that must be awaited.

when using async I have tried to use `await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(...)` to no avail, nothing happens

I tried to use fastapi's background task. It still gets stuck at `client.messages.create` (I am guessing this is a wrapper around `asyncio.to_thread` or `run_in_executor`)

What the hell am I doing wrong?

PS: I am aware of the twilio client's AsyncHTTPClient, but I am primarily interested in understand why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The synchronous call is blocking the event loop. That means *nothing* else can occur while the blocking call is occurring. That's why you see that behavior. Running this in a thread or threadpool executor will be problematic because Twilio uses requests sessions (connection pooling) by default, which are not thread-safe.

Twilio has also [made note](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/issues/580#issuecomment-1044878129) that their client should not be considered thread-safe.

Thread safety issues can lead to problems like deadlocks. You *might* avoid this problem by creating your client as a threadlocal variable in the thread in which it's used, instead of reusing the same client potentially across threads.

You might also be able to turn off use of sessions/connection pooling to solve the issue (YMMV, other thread safety issues may still exist):

```py
from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient

client = Client(...,
                http_client=TwilioHttpClient(pool_connections=False)
)
```

Ultimately, your best bet would just be to use the async client.

Comment: Much appreciated, this is the clearest explanation I've seen.  Maybe my mental model of async python is broken, but why would nothing else being able to run cause the server to complete lock? My (wrong) intuition would be that it would eventually return, but not other requests would be able to run. My understanding is that sync paths in fastapi go to a separate threadpool, so would that mean using twilio in *any* thread could cause problems, causing any thread it was in to potentially deadlock?

Comment: @msmedes In async, only one thing ever runs at any given moment. It's a cooperative event loop where tasks must voluntarily yield (`await`) control back to the loop. If a function fails to yield back control in a reasonable amount of time, the whole system grinds to a halt. I'm not familiar enough with FastAPI/uvicorn to comment on its implementation, but yes, if you have threaded web workers sharing a single `requests` session thats a problem because that object is not thread-safe. But there are other concurrency models that may avoid the problem, like gevent "green" threads.

Comment: Welp I tried to use the async client and the same thing is happening. for example:

```python
@app.post('/test/)
async def test():
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token, http_client=AsyncTwilioHttpClient())
    message = await client.messages.create_async(
        messaging_service_sid=messaging_service_sid,
        body='message_content',
        # from_=twilio_number,
        to=phone_number,
    )
```

I've set `pool_connections=False`, that didn't help.  Really makes no sense since it will work if you call this code in an async function with `asyncio.run(function())

Comment: Hmm. There may be something else going on, then @msmedes

Comment: A break in the case: the twilio client works if I use `hypercorn` with the `asyncio` event loop.  If I have `hypercorn` use `uvloop` (like `uvicorn`) it does not work.  This makes me think the twilio client is only compatible with `asyncio`.  However, if I start `uvicorn` with `loop='asyncio'`, it still hangs.  I'm not sure if thats because `uvicorn` is ignoring the flag (I also uninstalled `uvloop` so it can't use it even if it wanted to).  I'm not really sure what this all means but it is progress.